# I don’t have a degree or experience in tech industry. How do I make a resume?

Tags: job-search, remote-work, degree

I want to clarify few things

I’m a self-taught programmer, I’ve been learning programming for the last 3 years and before I started to build projects. I was learning JavaScript with the problem-solving on the online judge. Last year I started to build a few amazing projects with web apps following modern technology such as:

- .microblogging site build with front end also back end with modern
  tech likes NodeJS, express, MongoDB
- .ecommerce site build back end with Django, PostgreSQL so on
- .food delivery service site build with mern-stack
- .discord bot build with typescript, NodeJS, express

All those are my side projects.

I’m really familiar with JavaScript, NodeJS, and I know a little bit about python, java, typescript, SQL, MySQL, MongoDB, PostgreSQL and for design knowledge about tools photoshop, illustrator, Figma and so on.

but I have another question I had been working as a Photographer for 7+ years and nowadays I’m currently working as a journalist also graphics designer a news portal office

All those my previous worked experience, outside of the company tech.

I know that I can put on my resume the tech project I had made.

Nowadays I'm taking to prepare myself to apply for a remote job at a tech company. But I'm a little bit confused about making my resume having no tech industry experience and no degree. Can I put on my resume my previous work photography or journalist though it doesn't relate to tech sign.

Can anyone suggest which site I can apply for a remote job.

Comment: Even with edits, you should check your grammar before you submit your resume anywhere. And are you asking about the resume or a list of sites to apply to?

Comment: Can you get testimonials or references from people you've done programming for? It's worth mentioning this in a cover letter, if not in a resume. The same would apply if you were self-employed or ran your own company. You may also be able to demo stuff you've worked on to prospective companies.

Comment: @Robiul,  You can apply for freelance jobs at upwork.com, which always has remote jobs for freelancers 100% of the time (because all their jobs are remote).  In addition, you can try to search for jobs at LinkedIn or other similar job websites. You can use the keyword "remote" when searching for jobs.

Comment: You can also try to take some online programming courses to earn some online certificates or degrees to put them on your resume.

Answer (score 7):

At your experience level, certainly put down any jobs you've had, regardless of how relevant. They show a commitment to work, if nothing else.

Aside from real-word programming experience, if I was looking at you, my worry is you've got no real world experience working with other people on a day-to-day basis. I would also be concerned that you don't have any experience in dealing with deadlines, working under a boss etc.

You should certainly make sure that you highlight how you collaborated with others, and how you can work well as part of a team. If you can work on any open source projects before you apply, that would really help.

Given the domain you're looking to move into, if I were you, I'd read up on Scrum, and try to see if you can change your current style of working to match that. At a bare minimum, you can do two week sprints, and things like sprint retrospectives. It may not map exactly well to what you do now, but it would certainly make you look more enticing if you know some of the typical processes that go on.

Comment: If you are creative enough, you could argue that taking a photo before the subject moves is working to a pretty tight deadline :D